# character counter not functioning when echoed repeatedly in a table

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to use the javascript character counter below in multiple textareas within my table. The problem is the counter only functions in the first row of my table. Subsequent rows with textareas echo "250 characters remaining", but do not function as intended. I'm not sure how to assign each character counter with a unique id so it functions in all textareas. Any help would be appreciated.

PHP:

```
echo "</td><td>";
echo '<form action="peerflagreview.php?foorbar=' . $foobar . '" method="post" id="FlagPeerReview">
<A NAME="#peer' . $foobar . '"> (<a href="#peer' . $foobar . '" class="show_hide2">Report</a>)
<textarea class="PeerFlag" value="" name="PeerFlag" id="PeerFlag2"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" value="Post" name="submit" />
<span id="PeerFlag2Span">250 characters remaining</span>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
echo "</td></tr>";
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#PeerFlag2").on('change keydown paste input', function(){
      updateCounter('#PeerFlag2');
});
function updateCounter(theTextAreaID) {
    var remaining = 250 - jQuery(theTextAreaID).val().length;
    jQuery(theTextAreaID + 'Span').text(remaining + ' characters remaining.');
}

$('textarea').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
        if (!event.shiftKey) $('#PeerFlag').submit();
});

</script>
```

Comment: ID's should be unique, you should be using a class name for something like this and rethink the method to target the correct textarea and out put.

Comment: Well $foobar contains a unique id for each row.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple demo so I don't see of much explain needed other than this will target the next span of the textarea in use.
I see you already have jQuery so this demo will also use jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".UserInput").on('input', function(){
        $(this).next("span").html(250 - this.value.length + " characters remaining");
    }).trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="UserInput"></textarea><span>this is filled automatically</span><br/>
<textarea class="UserInput"></textarea><span></span><br/>
<textarea class="UserInput"></textarea><span></span><br/>
<textarea class="UserInput"></textarea><span></span><br/>
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this help. Happy coding!

Comment: I cannot get your example to work with what I already have in the question above. I tried renaming the function to   $(".PeerFlag").on('input', function(){
and naming the textarea class="PeerFlag"

Comment: Are the span tags next to the element with the class of `PeerFlag` ? Please copy/paste your source into a jsfiddle.net so I can find the issue and try help you further.

Comment: Yes the class is peerflag

Comment: Then this should work just fine. Open your browser console to check for any error reports and be sure to check the jQuery library is loading

Comment: Your example works standalone, but when applied to mine it doesn't work. The jquery library is loaded. If you want to try modifying my example above I can give it a shot. Thanks again.